# Embed CommandBar into Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, commandbar

I'm not sure if this is at all possible, but I'd like to be able to 'embed' a CommandBar into an Access 2003 Form.

I'd like to do this because the nature of my application is such that its forms are 'floating' so it doesn't look like it was developed in Access.

I know I can put Command Buttons on the form, which would achieve something similar, but I'd like a way to differentiate between the two types of buttons.

I'll be using it (if it's possible) to have a help menu present on some Forms.

Any ideas would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Not sure if you can do that in VBA however you can have customized menu for your form. This is an Excel example by JKP. I guess you can amend it for Access as well. Anyways worth a try. [HERE](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/03/06/a-menu-on-a-userform/) is the link

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it wouldn't be possible in the 'proper' sense. I think I'll go down the route of having coloured labels which show a menu (in the style of a right-click / context) when clicked.

Comment: The code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770425/how-to-add-a-menu-item-to-the-default-right-click-context-menu has been helpful in achieving this. I changed it to a left click. I now have a way for my users to differentiate between the help and a 'normal' command button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve a similar effect by placing labels of a different color at the top of the form, then assign custom context menus to appear on left click. This is similar to the code found here:

[How to add a menu item to the default right click context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770425/how-to-add-a-menu-item-to-the-default-right-click-context-menu)