# CommandBarControl executing .OnAction before click on button

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

The code in my question in inspired by the solution in the answer provided by this question:
[How to add a menu item to the default right click context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770425/how-to-add-a-menu-item-to-the-default-right-click-context-menu)

I have a ListBox object on a form showing a list of Actions. I want the user to be able to right click an item of this list to show a contextual menu where he can either :

1. open a new form where he can view and edit the action (corresponds to the execution of a double click event on the list item)
2. delete the item from the list

   ```
   Private Sub List_actions_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single

       'set up commandBar
       Dim combo As CommandBarControl

       'Since it may have been defined in the past, it should be deleted,
       'or if it has not been defined in the past, the error should be ignored
       On Error Resume Next
       CommandBars("RCActionContextMenu").Delete
       On Error GoTo 0

       'Make this menu a popup menu
       With CommandBars.Add(Name:="RCActionContextMenu", Position:=msoBarPopup)
           Set combo = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
               combo.BeginGroup = True
               combo.Caption = "View action"              ' Add label the user will see
               combo.OnAction = "List_actions_DblClick"    'Add the name of a function to call

           Set combo = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
               combo.Caption = "Delete action"
               combo.OnAction = DelAction()
       End With

       If Button = acRightButton Then
           DoCmd.CancelEvent
           CommandBars("RCActionContextMenu").ShowPopup
       End If
   End Sub

   Public Function DelAction()
       If Not IsNull(Me.Controls("RCActionContextMenu").Column(0)) Then
           CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM T_ACTIONS " & _
                     "WHERE ID = " & List_actions.Column(9) & ";"
           MsgBox "Action supprimée", vbInformation, "Information"
       End If
   End Function

   Private Sub List_actions_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
       Dim vStatus As String

       'Get the record's index of the action
       rowNumber = Me.List_actions.ListIndex + 1

       id_action = List_actions.Column(9, rowNumber)
       vStatus = List_actions.Column(5, rowNumber)

       'Open the action
       DoCmd.OpenForm "F_ACTIONS", , , "[ID] = " & List_actions.Column(9)

       Form_F_ACTIONS.Effective_date.Visible = Effdatefunction(vStatus)

   End Sub
   ```

The problem i get is that the DelAction() function is executed before the pop-up is shown and i get a `run-time error 2465` stating `"Microsoft Access can't find the field 'RCActionContextMenu' referred to in your expression."`
I've tried repalcing the row `combo.OnAction = DelAction()` by `combo.OnAction = "DelAction"`. It results in the conextual menu showing itself but nothing happens when i click on either button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

```
        combo.OnAction = DelAction()
```

This will call the function, as you have seen. You need to set a string here.

```
        combo.OnAction = "DelAction()"
```

This still won't work, since `DelAction()` is in your form module.
Either move the function to a public module, with parameters, or hardcoding the object names there,

```
combo.OnAction = "DelAction(""MyFormName"", ""List_actions"")"
```

or try (not sure if this works):

```
        combo.OnAction = "Form_YourFormName_DelAction()"
```

It's the same with `"List_actions_DblClick"` - the function needs to be called "from the outside", like from the Immediate window.

---

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Controls("RCActionContextMenu").Column(0)) Then
```

You context menu command bar isn't a control, what you want is the list box:

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Controls("List_actions").Column(0)) Then
```

or simply

```
If Not IsNull(Me!List_actions.Column(0)) Then
```

---

After deleting an action, you need to requery the listbox.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM T_ACTIONS " ...
Me!List_actions.Requery
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed i needed to put the functions in a public module so they get called correctly.

Comment: The only problem i have now is that the 'Me' keyword doesn't work in this public module. Should I pass the List_Actions Listbox as a parameter?