# Is there any way to run a .lnk file on my desktop and wait for it to complete?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have several .lnk files on my desktop that fetch data from other files that I use in my database.  These files copy data to the clipboard that I then paste into the displayed form.  I want to do this in Access VBA, rather then jumping to the desktop and clicking on the file.

Comment: [Analyse .LNK files](https://www.howtogeek.com/190897/how-can-you-open-and-edit-windows-.lnk-shortcut-files/) to convert them to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript) to execute`.LNK`files.

```vb
Sub ExecuteLink(ByVal Path As String)
Const dQuote As String = """"

With CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    .Run dQuote & Path & dQuote, 4, True
End With
End Sub
```

But you still have to paste the clipboard data (can be [automated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard) too).

Instead fetching data (from a query?) to clipboard, fetch data in VBA and insert it to the form.

If you can't automate the selected field to insert you can use a [context menu entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770425/how-to-add-a-menu-item-to-the-default-right-click-context-menu) to select a control and execute the VBA-Code.

Comment: Thank you for Wscript.  This solves half of my problem.  Next:  How to wait for the hidden executable in the ,lnk file to end?

Comment: As [bWaitOnReturn](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) is true, it should do that, but using vba instead of lnk would solve that too.

Answer (score 0):

As this is getting to complicated, I am going to start a new simpler thread on running "Microsoft Solitaire Collection" using Access VBA.